# python requests call works without proxy but throws 502 error with proxy

Tags: python, python-requests, proxy

I am trying to check if a site is available or not. For this I do requests get calls to the site and check the response status. I have couple of websites that do not work with proxies. They work fine without proxies, but with proxies I get 502 error and the text says Failed to initialize SSL tunnel

```
import requests
import urllib3

urllib3.disable_warnings(urllib3.exceptions.InsecureRequestWarning)

proxies = {"https": "http://pwd:@proxy.crawlera.com:8010/",
           "http": "http://pwd:@proxy.crawlera.com:8010/"}
url = "https://mpbhulekh.gov.in/mpbhulekh.do"

resp = requests.get(
    url,
    proxies=proxies,
    #proxies=None,
    verify=False,
    timeout=180
)
content = resp.text
status_code = resp.status_code
print(f"Response status code: {status_code}")

if status_code == 200 or status_code == 201:
    print("True")
else:
    print("False")
    print(f"{resp.text}")
```

This code gives the below output

```
PS C:\Users\visha\PycharmProjects\site_checker> python .\test.py
Response status code: 502
False
Failed to initialize SSL tunnel
```

Any ideas why this is no working

Comment: Is it perhaps because the proxy requires a password?

Comment: I am providing the API Key in the proxies dictionary. This works for 8 other URLS, but just the tow URLs it throws 502 error